# How can I clear a text box by using messageboxbuttons.yesno?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to clear a text box by using messageboxbuttons.yesno. If he chooses to start another conversion then clear the text box. I don't what's wrong.
    Public Class Form1

```
    Private Sub BtnFah_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnFah.Click
        Try
            Dim intFah As Integer

            intFah = CInt(TxtBoxTemp.Text)
            intFah = (intFah * 9) / 5 - 32
            MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If intFah = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                TxtBoxTemp.Clear()
            ElseIf intFah = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then

            End If
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It [reads](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071203101453AAxjvrS) as if `MessageBox.Text = ""`, but I don't have access to Visual Basic, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

you are not storing the result from the message box....the line:

```
If intFah = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
```

Is not correct because you're trying to compare the temperature you're calculating to a dialog result.

If you follow the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then you should see how to capture the result from the message box and then perform the appropriate action.

Your usage of the Clear() method is also OK in a VB context, the other way would be to:

```
TxtBoxTemp.Text = String.Empty
```

But either way is OK.

HTH, Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `MessageBox.Show()` directly in the `If`

```
Private Sub BtnFah_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnFah.Click
    Try
        Dim intFah As Integer
        intFah = CInt(TxtBoxTemp.Text)
        intFah = (intFah * 9) / 5 - 32
        If MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            TxtBoxTemp.Text = String.Empty
        Else

        End If
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It also clears the text box when I press no. I did some changes to the code but it's not working. What can I do?

Comment: If you still have a problem you should post your code (e.g. do an edit to your original question and insert the revised code which isn't working) - it'll make it easier to help